# Loop through a multiple dictionary that contain classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I loop over multiple dictionaries that contains classes. I don't really know what to explain more about it. If you have any questions just comment down below

```
class Stats:
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

inte = {1: Stats(name='Programming', exp=0, description="This is a description"),
        2: Stats(name='Reading', exp=0, description='Reading Description'),
        3: Stats(name='Meditating', exp=0, description='Meditaing Description')}

stre = {1: Stats(name='Excercise', exp=0, description="This is a description"),
        2: Stats(name='Gym', exp=0, description="Gym description")}

will = {1: Stats(name='Resistance', exp=0, description="This is a description"),
        2: Stats(name='Chores', exp=0, description='Chores description')}

# Works with every single dictionary but how to do it with multiple?
for k, v in stre.items():
    if v.name == "Excercise"
    print("You did excercise")
```

Is there a way to search through a list of dictionaries? Like search in the three of them at once, then compare everything then if something match print there exp? While I can get around by coding every dictionaries, I believe there is more optimized and efficient way to do this. Thankyou :D

Comment: This isn't valid code; you need to fix your indentation.

Comment: @chepner should I put all the code? I thought this was all that is relevant to the topic that's why I didn't put everything. MB

Comment: Initially, I will add all of the dictionaries to a list object... then traverse a list and check for some some property for the `Stats`object.

Comment: I didn't say it was irrelevant; I said it was *invalid*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm *pretty sure* that you just need to create a collection (list) of the dictionaries and loop over that.  Something like this:

```
traits = [inte, stre, will]
```

How you loop over them is kind of up to you.  You can do it with nested for loops:

```
for trait in traits:
  for k, v in trait.items():
    # checks and prints here
```

You can add some syntactic sugar to save some indentation if you want:

```
for k, v in [trait.items() for trait in traits]:
  # checks and prints here
```